# mpdf columns and full width images

Tags: mpdf

I am using mpdf to generate a pdf. I need a 2 columns layout for the text, but on some pages, I need to add an full width image to the page. See example:

[image: How it should look like]

I tried this:

```
<columns column-count="2" vAlign="justify" column-gap="10">
    asd dsadsa...
</columns>
<pagebreak />
<columns column-count="0">
    <img src="someimage.jpg" class='content-img' />
</columns>
<columns column-count="2" vAlign="justify" column-gap="10">
    asd dsadsa...
</columns>
<columns column-count="0">
    <img src="someimage.jpg" class='content-img' />
</columns>
```

Where the 'content-img' class just adds the width to the image:

```
.content-img {
    width: 180mm;
}
```

But when i do this, I get big margin after the first image - see example:

[image: Big margin]

And I can't remove it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Set to IMG something like css style "padding-bottom: -200px" (only for first page images).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found that wrapping images and all content in general in `<p>...</p>` helps with such issues!